# What is the pin distance of GPIO

Tags: gpio, hardware

I'm going to buy necessary stuff for using the GPIO from [a Czech reseller](http://www.gme.cz/pocitacove-konektory/) to avoid the shipping costs. For this, I need to know: What is the nominal distance of the pins on the GPIO?

*(I don't have my RPi here to measure it.)*

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question is valuable since I found the answer myself. If it gets closed/deleted, I won't feel offended.

Answer (score 8):

Found it [on the official forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=41715&p=345998), it's 2x13 pins, distance is 0.1in = 2.54mm.